# Remix says "server code in client modules" but that doesn't seem to be the problem

Tags: remix, remix.run

Just migrated an application from react to Remix and I'm getting an error which doesn't help me to debug.

I have a page that imports a custom component:

```
import SimGraph2 from "~/components/similarity/SimGraph2"
```

The complete contents of the custom component are as follows:

```
export default function SimGraph2(props:any) {
    return (
        <div></div>
    )
}
```

When I add the component to my page like so:

```
<SimGraph2></SimGraph2>
```

I get the following error (in the browser):

```
Error: Cannot initialize 'routeModules'. This normally occurs when you have server code in your client modules.
Check this link for more details:
https://remix.run/pages/gotchas#server-code-in-client-bundles
    at invariant2 (invariant.js:13:11)
    at RemixRoute (components.js:176:3)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:18)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811:13)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049:16)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:3945:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:31)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:7)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22779:12)
```

When I take the component out of the page, everything starts working again.  Given that there is no server-side stuff going on, I don't think this error is being reported correctly.  But I also have no idea where to look to fix this now.  Any help appreciated.

**Update (2022-09-30):**
Right before the routeModules error this shows up in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'React' has already been declared (at index-UZP4PAJK.js:9564:5)
```

Nowhere in my code do I declare React explicitly, so I'm not sure where this is coming from.

Comment: Look in dev console and look at the error prior to this one. That is typically the root cause.

Comment: The error basically means that there was a JS error while trying to load the route modules. Because of the error, Remix couldn't initialize it's internal state.

Comment: I updated the answer to include the error before the routeModules error